# How to output every value of a array header

Tags: php, arrays, loops, csv

I have the following code:

```
$csv_data = array_map('str_getcsv', file('exmaple.csv'));
$csv_header = $csv_data[0];
unset($csv_data[0]);

foreach($csv_data as &$row)
{
    $rows[] = array_combine($csv_header, $row);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($rows);
echo '<pre>';
```

and following output:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
     (
         [ID] => 1
         [article] => 000001
     )

     [1] => Array
     (
         [ID] => 2
         [article] => 000002
     )

)
```

I need a loop that outputs each id,

how can I display the id of any array simple like:

```
1
2
```

I can only get an ID with a following order out:

```
print_r($rows[0]['ID']);
```

Comment: [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: Please refer to basic manuals for iterating over arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_column` to get the specific column values from sub-arrays

```
$ids = array_column($a, 'ID')
```

If you want ids alone use foreach

```
foreach($rows as $row){
   echo $row['ID']."\n";
}
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/9m3qF

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want id's to stand alone, like: 1 and not like:     [0] => 1

Comment: @Sternisic Antwort wurde aktualisiert